# How can I draw the split the chart in RN project

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

Thanks for your time to review my question.

Now I have some problem with `React-native-chart` IN RN project.

How can I draw the split the chart such as below the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhVcx.png)

I've tried to use the `react-native-gifted-charts` module. But it dose not working well